# How to split page in half horizontally in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, grids

This should be simple question. I just want to know how to split page 50% horizontally without annoying grid. Just a absolutely simple dividing line at 5.% of the page.

Comment: Welcome! What is the problem with the grid? Please explain your question better ...

Comment: When I use it, it is really messy because lots of line.

Answer (score 3):

Simply drag down a new ruler guide from the horizontal ruler:

[image]

If you have *Smart Guides* turned on, it will snap to the middle of the page.

Read more about ruler guides in [Adobe Help Center](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/ruler-guides.html).